# Change value of Ruby variable in ERB file upon onclick

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I want to change the value of a Ruby local parameter in my .erb file when a user clicks on a bit of text. (I am using Ruby with Sinatra, not Rails). The code looks like this:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    <!-- Get ERB to work here -->
    <p><i>No account? <a href="#" onlick="<% new_user = !new_user %>">Register here</a></i></p> <!-- Should change new_user to true if clicked -->
    <form class="input-group" style="margin: 0 auto" method="POST" action="/nanotwitter/v1.0/users/session">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
      <br><br>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      <% if new_user %>
        <br><br>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Repeat password">
      <% end %>
      <br><br>
      <div class="input-group" style="margin: 0 auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default form-control" style="width: 50%" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" style="width: 50%" type="submit">
          <% if new_user %>
          Register
          <% else %>
          Log In
          <% end %>
        </button>
      </div>
      </form>
  </div>
```

So obviously the Ruby code in the onlick attribute evaluates immediately, and I want it to only execute when the user clicks. I've searched this site and the internet, and I'm still not sure what the correct/standard implementation for this would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ruby dont interact with user events. Javascript does.
Second, what is `new_user` ? Simple variable? You want to use it to, say, swap forms for sign up\ sign in ? Or you want user to really register through this method?

If the case is to show sign in\ sign up form to user based oh his choice (new\registered), you should do it with only javascript.

In general, you should prepare markup for two different forms (register\login) and hide them according to some javascript variable, which user can choose.

Comment: So you are saying the variable should be assigned/changed with Javascript, right? (Yes, new_user is a simple variable.)

So the markup for the two different forms is really similar - I thought I could reduce the repetition using erb logic. You're saying this is incorrect, and that I should repeat the two forms and just display one or the other based on the JS variable?